# MathML support for strikethrough

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Some MathML / MathJax sites [have support for strikethrough](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mathjax-users/tuFHn3EkSic) enabled:

```
     MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
       var TEX = MathJax.InputJax.TeX;
       var MML = MathJax.ElementJax.mml;
       TEX.Definitions.macros.cancel  =  ["myCancel",MML.NOTATION.UPDIAGONALSTRIKE];
       TEX.Definitions.macros.bcancel =  ["myCancel",MML.NOTATION.DOWNDIAGONALSTRIKE];
       TEX.Parse.Augment({
         myCancel: function (name,notation) {
           var mml = this.ParseArg(name);
           this.Push(MML.menclose(mml).With({notation:notation}));
         }
       });
     });
```

This code enables the use of \cancel and \bcancel respectively. These macros don't seem to work on our site:

\$ \cancel{(2 + 2)} \$

Since some of our answers deal with derivations, having the ability to do a strikethrough may help with translating written derivations into electronic format.

There is a \not function, but it strikes through only a single character (not an expression).

Thoughts / comments?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40253 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4465/5773 ?

Comment: The code example I posted enables \cancel and \bcancel on the server-side. When I tried to use those tags on this SE site, they didn't work. (Question updated with these details)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You no longer need to add `\cancel` anc `\bcancel` yourself, as they are now part of the `cancel` extension that was made available as part of MathJax v2.0.  If you are running your own site, you can include this in your TeX extensions:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {extensions: ["cancel.js"]}
});
```

Otherwise, if you are using an SE site with MathJax that doesn't load this for you, use

```
\require{cancel}
```

within your mathematics and that will load it for you.  E.g.

```
$$\require{cancel} \cancel{2-2}$$
```

gives

$$\require{cancel} \cancel{2-2}.$$

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the support.

Comment: Added it to the cheat sheet http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/1245/8627